# flatten MongoDB table

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a MongoDB table of events with the following columns:
**Id, DateOn, DateOff, State**
It saves for each event Id the date it was first created and the date it was finished (if it is done).
Each time an event is recreated a new row is added, an event can be recreated only after it was finished.

for example

| ID | DateOn | DateOff | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12/01/22 11:00 | 12/01/22 11:05 | false |
| 12 | 12/01/22 11:06 | null | true |
| 13 | 12/01/22 11:00 | null | true |
| 14 | 12/01/22 11:40 | 13/04/23 11:50 | false |

I want to get a table in the below structure without really changing my own table in order to get the last Event status quickly (true/false) before a specified date and after another specified date.
for example, I want to know if event id - 12 was true or false last time before or equal to 11:05

I think that I need some queries to make the table like this (flat):

| ID | Date | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12/01/22 11:00 | true |
| 12 | 12/01/22 11:05 | false |
| 12 | 12/01/22 11:06 | true |
| 13 | 12/01/22 11:00 | true |
| 14 | 12/01/22 11:40 | true |
| 14 | 13/04/23 11:50 | false |

then order by the Date desc because we have only one Date column and take the first row before the specified date and find out the event status.

what is the best way to do it?

Is it possible to do it in one query or one stored procedure if I want to get 2 answers?

1. event status last time before date X
2. event status first time after date Y

and if I want to run this query for 180 different events? can i do it in one query or one stored procedure? or I have to do 2 queries for each event.

What is the most efficient way to do it?

I am working with c# so I have the MongoDB driver with the Linq option to write queries but I am new in the MongoDb so I really don't know if it is possible and how.

Thanks for your help.

I have tried
 `return _Db.Query.SelectMany(a => new List<ShortEvent>{ new ShortEvent { Date = a.TimeOn.Value, State = true, EventId = a.EventId },{ new ShortEvent { Date = a.TimeOff.Value, State = false, EventId = a.EventId }  }).ToList();`
that created an exception.
I am expected for a MongoDB expert solution.

Comment: Please provide sample data as JSON text.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you like to get, why do you think you need to flatten the data?

I guess, this simple query returns the desired result:

```
db.collection.find({
   $or: [
      { dateOn: { $lte: ISODate('2022-12-01T11:40') }, state: true },
      { dateOn: { $lte: ISODate('2022-12-01T11:40') }, dateOff: { $gte: ISODate('2022-12-01T11:40') }, state: false },
   ]
})
```

Should be no big deal to transform this into C# query.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/993i_6VEHjN)